# Scala: Using self types to implement a strategy pattern

Tags: scala, types, traits, mixins

I'm attempting to implement a strategy pattern for a class I have that manages state. The strategy implementations should have access to the protected/public members of the class which uses those strategies, and the class using the strategies needs access to the public members of the strategy.

I've got this working, except I can't really figure out how to do this without creating different top-level classes per-strategy. Here is an example:

```
class BranchState(a: String, b: Int) extends ABranchState(a, b) with QueuedStrat

class ABranchState(a: String, b: Int) {
  this: ChainingStrategy =>
    .... lots of impl ....
}

trait ChainingStrategy {
  self: BranchState =>
    ... headers only, no impl ...
}

trait QueuedStrat extends ChainingStrategy {
   self: BranchState =>
    .... impl ....
}

trait AnotherStrat extends ChainingStrategy {
   self: BranchState =>
    .... impl ....
}
```

The problem here is if I want to instantiate a BranchState with uses `AnotherStrat`, I have to make another class. I've tried to add a type parameter to BranchState like `[T <: ChainingStrategy]` but that doesn't work because the compiler (rightfully) complains I have to have implementations for the headers in `ChainingStrategy`. It seems like I need some mechanism to say "some type which implements chaining strategy *fully*, IE: has no unimplemented methods".

Maybe that's just not the right way at all, though. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting in terms of language mechanics, but seems complex as a design. Why would the strategy need to know about the class using the strategy ? Doesn't feel right.

Comment: Yes, I can think of plenty other ways to organize this, and I probably shouldn't have called them "strategies" here because it's really not the same pattern and that seems to be confusing. I am mainly interested in making this mechanism work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do does make any sense in term of design. You are trying to treat your strategies as if they were states. But **a Strategy is not any specialization or generalization of a State**, so I don't think they should have any inheritance relationship.

Moreover, in Scala one should not be needing the Strategy Pattern, due to the functional aspect of the language, you could take a real advantage of [Higher-order Functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html) (I recommend you to read: [How Scala killed the Strategy Pattern](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-scala-killed-oop-strategy-design-pattern), Alvin Alexander).

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I'm treating the strategies as differences in the way state is manipulated. Perhaps the "BranchState" name is confusing here - it's not just a data container. It exposes a public API for applying events that result in changes in the state. I'm need a convenient way to allow strategies to have access to the non-public members of BranchState. I'm aware of higher-order funcs, but using them here would mean passing nearly all the fields of BranchState back and forth. This seemed more elegant. Another way to frame my problem would be "how can I an inner class in a separate file".

Comment: The other option I have is simply sticking all this in a sub-package and making the BranchState fields that need to be manipulated by the strategies be `private[package]`, but I was interested to learn if I could make this mechanic work.

Comment: Well I'm thinking of something not very clean, you could to implement all the headers in `ChainStrategy` and make them throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. That would solve your problem but this would transfer error detection from compiler to runtime but I am not a fan at all.